Laravel Eloquent belongsToMany missing third unrelated column
I have a oneToMany relationship defined here: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many except my role_user table has an additional column (district_id):
role_user

user_id

role_id

district_id


When calling the following:
$usersTable = User::with('roles')->get(); it isn't returning that district_id field. I tried adding a hasOne relationship for the district on the Role model to no luck:
public function district() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\District');
} 

How can I retrieve the district model or at the very least, the district_id assigned to the record?

If you do a dd($userTable); on the get() example, what is the output?

I believe this section of the documentation is what you need: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns
